# Trouble with my python code: Load from file won't work as a function, has to be in game loop. Why?

Tags: python, function, readline

I am writing a simple text based adventure game in python.  I will include all of the code because I have no idea what the problem is (it isn't too long and it's quite simple).

In order to save, I am writing to a text file the name of the 'currentRoom' and each item in 'you.inventory'.  Then when I load I am using 'readline()' to retrieve that data and reset the variables.  I've got a "game loop" where I get the next command and perform whatever function matches the command.  When I wrote the following code for 'load', it wouldn't work correctly.  To test the save/load, I start the game pick up a few items and then go north to get into a position that is not the starting room, and save.  Then I quit, run the game again, enter the same name of course, and then give command 'load'.  Note, the saved file is correct.  I even included a print statement in the load function that prints currentRoom.name, and it's correct, but then when I call the look function and it does the exact same 'print currentRoom.name', I've been moved back to the starting room!?  Interestingly, the inventory is loaded fine, just the location is wrong.  I can't figure it out for the life of me.

In order to fix this, I had to move the load() function into the game loop body, under 'elif com == "load"..., rather than calling it as a function, and then it works!?  I suspect I'm doing something wrong with global vs local variables, but I can't see what.

Here's the code: (sorry for the indentation errors, cut and paste didn't work well)

```
class Character(object):
inventory = []
hitPoints = 20
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name=name

class Room(object):
  def __init__(self, name, exits):
    self.name=name
    self.exits=exits
    self.contents=[]

class Item(object):
  def __init__(self, name, itemType, keyWords):
    self.name = name
    self.itemType = itemType
    self.keyWords = keyWords
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
#Item types: weapon1 (one handed), weapon 2 (2handed), head, body, hands, feet, arms,     legs, ring, necklace
#****************** I T E M S *************************

sword1 = Item("A short sword", "weapon1", ["sword1","sword","shortsword"])
sword1.roomDescription = "A short sword made of steel lies here."
sword1.description = "It is a small sword of average quality, made of steel."

helmet1 = Item("A metal helmet", "head", ["helmet1", "helmet", "metal"])
helmet1.roomDescription = "A simple metal helmet sits on the ground."
helmet1.description = "It's a simple helmet with a few dings and dents, but otherwise     good condition."

coat1 = Item("A leather coat", "body", ["coat1", "coat", "leather"])
coat1.roomDescription = "A rugged leather coat lies crumpled at your feet."
coat1.description = "It's a thick leather coat.  It looks like it might offer some protection."

ring1 = Item("A brass ring", "ring", ["ring1", "ring", "brass"])
ring1.roomDescription = "A small brass ring is here."
ring1.description = "It's a simple brass ring.  Not very exciting."

necklace1 = Item("A silver necklace", "necklace", ["necklace1", "necklace", "brass"])
necklace1.roomDescription = "A thin silver necklace has been cast aside."
necklace1.description = "It's a shiny silver necklace."

#****************** PEOPLE AND NPC's *************************

you = Character("Monty")

#****************** R O O M S *************************

r0 = Room("Purgatory", [])

r1 = Room("Home",["north"])
r1.description = "You are in your home.  It's a small room.  There is a door in the north wall."
r1.contents = [sword1, sword1, ring1, necklace1, coat1]
r1.id = "r1"

r2 = Room("Main Street", ["south"])
r2.description = "You are north of your home in Main street.  The only exit is south."
r2.contents = [helmet1, coat1, sword1, sword1, coat1, coat1, coat1, coat1, coat1, coat1,  coat1, coat1, coat1, coat1, coat1]
r2.id = "r2"

#****************** E X I T S *************************

r1.n = r2
r2.s = r1

#****************** V A R I A B L E S *************************

nextRoom=0
nextMove="z"
quitVar=0
currentRoom = r1

#****************** F U N C T I O N S *************************

def printExits():
  print currentRoom.exits
  return

def look():
  print currentRoom.name
  print currentRoom.description
  if currentRoom.contents != []:
    for i in currentRoom.contents:
        print "- "+i.roomDescription

def save():
f = open(you.name+"saved.txt","w")
f.write(currentRoom.id+"\n")
for i in you.inventory:
    f.write(i.keyWords[0]+"\n")
f.write("*end*")
f.close()
print "Saved!"

def load():
f = open(you.name+"saved.txt","r")
currentRoom=eval(f.readline())
tempItem="none"
while tempItem != "*end*":
    tempItem = f.readline()
    if tempItem != "*end*":
        inventoryItem=eval(tempItem)
        you.inventory.append(inventoryItem)
f.close()
print "Loaded!"
print"****",
print currentRoom.name
look()

def printInventory():
print "You are carrying:"
if you.inventory ==[]:
    print "Nothing!"
    return
for i in you.inventory:
    print i

def getItem(itemKeyword0, typed_string): #itemKeyword0 is first keyWord (same as variable name for object) in first item in room that matches typed input
                                                   #typed_string is exactly what the user types following 'get '
if len(you.inventory)>=15:
    print "You can't carry any more!"
    return
currentRoom.contents.remove(eval(itemKeyword0)) #remove picked up item from room
you.inventory.append(eval(itemKeyword0))  #add picked up item to inventory
print 'You get the %s.' % (typed_string)

def dropItem(itemKeyword0, typed_string): #itemKeyword0 is first keyWord in first item in inventory that matches typed string
you.inventory.remove(eval(itemKeyword0)) #remove object from inventory that matches keyword0
currentRoom.contents.append(eval(itemKeyword0)) #add object to room that matches keyword0
print 'You drop the %s.' % (typed_string)
you.name = (raw_input("What is your name?")).lower()

look()
while quitVar < 1:
  com = (raw_input(">>")).lower() #get next command in lower case
  nextMove="z" #reset nextMove
  print ""
  if com == "help":
    print"north(n), south(s), east(e), west(w), quit, help, look(l), exits,   inventory(i), get, drop"
elif com == "load":
    load()
elif com == "quit":
    quitVar += 10
elif com == "exits":
    printExits()
elif com == "look" or com == "l":
    look()
elif com == "get all":
    itemGotCounter = 0 #needed counter to make it not say 'There's nothing here!' after getting all
    while len(currentRoom.contents)>0 and len(you.inventory)<15: #for some reason the following for i excluded the last item in the room.
        for i in currentRoom.contents:
            getItem(i.keyWords[0],i.keyWords[1])
            itemGotCounter = 1
    else:
        if len(currentRoom.contents)==0 and itemGotCounter == 0:
            print "There's nothing here!"
        if len(you.inventory) >= 15:
            print "You can't carry any more!"       
elif com[0:4] == "get " and com != "get all":
    gottenItem = com[4:] #set equal to string user typed
    for i in currentRoom.contents: #loop through room items, setting equal to i
        if gottenItem in i.keyWords: #if typed string matches with i.keywords
            getItem(i.keyWords[0], gottenItem) #send first keyword of item to getItem function, and send typed string
            break
    else:
        print "You do not see that here!"
elif com == "drop all":
    while len(you.inventory)>0:
        for i in you.inventory:
            dropItem(i.keyWords[0], i.keyWords[1])
elif com[0:5] == "drop " and com != "drop all":
    droppedItem = com[5:] #equal to string user typed
    if you.inventory == []: #check if user is carrying anything to drop
        print "You aren't carrying anything!"
    for i in you.inventory: #cycle through users inventory
        if droppedItem in i.keyWords: #if typed string matches keywords in users inventory
            dropItem(i.keyWords[0], droppedItem) #send first keyWord of that inventory item to dropItem function, and typed string
            break
    else:
        print "You don't have one!"
elif com == "inventory" or com == "i":
    printInventory()
elif com == "n" or com == "north":
    if "north" in currentRoom.exits:
        nextMove="n"
        nextRoom=currentRoom.n
    else:
        print "You can't go that way!"
elif com == "s" or com == "south":
    if "south" in currentRoom.exits:
        nextMove="s"
        nextRoom=currentRoom.s
    else:
        print "You can't go that way!"
elif com == "e" or com == "east":
    if "east" in currentRoom.exits:
        nextMove="e"
        nextRoom=currentRoom.e
    else:
        print "You can't go that way!"
elif com == "w" or com == "west":
    if "west" in currentRoom.exits:
        nextMove="w"
        nextRoom=currentRoom.w
    else:
        print "You can't go that way!"
elif com == "":
    pass
elif com == "save":
    save()

else:
    print "Huh?"
print "****"
print nextMove
print currentRoom.name
print "****"

if nextMove !="z": #If a move has occurred, move to nextRoom and look
    currentRoom = nextRoom
    look()

print "See ya later, alligator!",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope!

```
def update ():
    a=2
    print (a)

a=1
update ()
print (a)
# prints 2 then 1
```

however

```
def update ():
    global a
    a=2
    print (a)

a=1
update ()
print (a)
# prints 2 then 2
```

Comment: Your last bit of example code is invalid. (Actually, doubly invalid, since it gives a syntax error because of missing `()` in the `def` statement when it's declared, before it can be run.) If you run it you'll get an `UnboundLocalError` from the first print statement. That's because any time a variable can be written to within a function, it is assumed by the compiler to be a local variable for the whole function (even the parts that came earlier). The rest of your answer is good though!

Comment: You're right, I am kind of stupid. I just deleted the last part.

Comment: Please write whole sentences like: "It's because of scope!". This way your answer is more useful and more likely to be upvoted.

Comment: Thank you!  I was going crazy with that one.  A simple as a local vs global variable.  \*slap self\*